# Como construir o algoritmo abaixo em pseudocodigo?

Tags: visualg, pseudocódigo

Construa um algoritmo que seja possível ler dois vetores de 3 elementos do tipo caractere e pergunte ao usuario qual o candidato ele quer votar
e que seja armazenado o resultado da operação
em outros vetores. Demostre em tela os resultados da votação

Minha tentativa:

```
Algoritmo "eleicao"

Var

candidato: vetor[1..3] de caractere
resultado: vetor[1..3] de caractere
i: inteiro

Inicio

candidato[1] <- "maria"
candidato[2] <- "joao"
candidato[3] <- "ana"

para i de 1 ate 3 faca
    escreval ("Candidatos")
    escreval ("----------")
    escreval ("maria, joao, ana")
    escreval ()
    escreval ("escolha seu candidato: ")
    leia (resultado[i])
    limpatela
fimpara

Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Fala Gabriel, seria interessante você mostrar o que você já tentou e em que pé está no momento, pois no SO estamos pra ajudar e não fazer por você :)

Comment: Adiciona o código que implementou até agora.

Comment: como eu faria para mostrar o resultado acumulado?

Comment: Creio que seu vetor resultado deva ser um vetor de inteiros, inicializado com zeros e a cada voto recebido pelo candidato[i] resultado[i] seja incrementado de 1. Ao final resultado terá a quantidade de votos recebidos por cada candidato. O seu loop deve se repetir pelo total de votantes, e não o número de candidatos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var
Voto: Vetor [1..2] de inteiro
cont: inteiro
Cod: Vetor [1..2] de inteiro
valor1,valor2: inteiro
sair,resultado: caractere

inicio
Escreval ("35 - Fernando")
Cod[1] <- 35
Escreval ("45 - Julia")
Cod[2] <- 45



Cont <- 1
Repita
   Escreval ("Digite o código do candidato desejado:")
   Leia (Voto[cont])

   Se (Voto[cont] = cod[1]) então

      Valor1 <- (Valor1 + 1)

   Fimse

   Se (Voto[cont] = Cod[2]) então

      Valor2 <- (Valor2 + 1)

   Fimse

   Escreval ("Próximo a votar (Caso nenhum, digite SAIR):")
   Leia (sair)



Ate (sair = "SAIR")
Escreval ("Deseja ver o resultado?")
Leia (resultado)

Se (Resultado = "SIM") então
   Escreval ("Total de votos em Fernando:", Valor1)
   Escreval ("Total de votos em Julia:", Valor2)

Fimse

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: consegui aqui, vlw

Comment: Tamo junto guerreiro